# Bad Credentials Error when using InMemoryUserDetailsManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am new to Spring and have been following a Spring Security JWT tutorial by Dan Vega. It's been going ok but I keep having an issue with the following code. Whenever I go to localhost and try to login with the credentials below. I keep getting a bad credentials error, but when I login with 'user' and the auto-generated password I am able to login just fine. I don't know if i'm missing something crucial and just unable to see it. Can anyone help me please.

````
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests( auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager users() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("myname")
                        .password("{noop}password")
                        .authorities("read")
                        .build()
        );
    }

}```


I have even tried refactoring it as so but even that hasn't helped the issue...
````

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService users() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("{noop}password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Comment: which spring boot version are you using?

Comment: @VipulKumar I am using version 3.1.3

Comment: all should work without any problem, can you also show how you are doing request of Authentication ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa sorry what do you mean please? I am just going to localhost:8080 on my browser and logging in when I am redirected to http://localhost:8080/login. Did you mean show some other part of my code?

Comment: because i tried you code and all work well, authentication is passing

Comment: if you are seeing an auto generated password in the logs, means that your security configuration is not picked up by Spring Security, which means that spring is using the default security configuration. Your configuration file needs to be placed either in the root package next to file containing the main function, or in a package, beneath the file that contains the main function.

Comment: by the way into `securityFilterChain` also add `.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())`

Comment: also @Toerktumlare wrote a good point, check your package structure.

Comment: @AndreiLisa it depends on what he is going for, if he wants basic login, he wants basic, if he wants form he wants form. If he is using basic login, he should get a web browser popup that asks him to insert his credentials. What he should remove is what says his application should be STATELESS, because otherwise he will need to login multiple times.

Comment: @Toerktumlare OMG thank you! i moved my config package into the same package containing the main function and it worked! Thank you so much!! (also I'm a she lol :D )

Comment: i apologize for assuming your gender, that was my bad. Remember to remove the line saying stateless. If you have that, the server will not remember you between requests after you have logged in.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom explicit security configuration, the `@SpringBootApplication` on the main function means that spring will search for spring beans and configuration classes recursively from the location of the file that contains the main function.

In the question it was pointed out that she could see a default password generated in the spring security logs.

This means that Spring Security is using its [default configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html#servlet-hello-starting) and any defined custom security has not been found by spring security.

This also probably means that the security configuration is not placed in either the same package, or a subpackage beneath the class/file that contains the main function.